# What anions does the loss of a proton from HOCN and HNCO produce? Are they same or different?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, tautomer, nitriles

> What anions does the loss of a proton from $\ce{HOCN}$ and $\ce{HNCO}$ produce? Are they same or different?

Once, I had asked my teacher if $\ce{HCN}$ and $\ce{ HNC }$ are different or same compunds, he said they were different and yes, they had different structures. Applying the same logic here, $\ce{OCN-}$ and $\ce{NCO-}$ are different anions because they'll have different structures.

Comment: Slightly related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/53568/what-is-the-structural-formula-of-alkali-hypohalite-mox-or-mxo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When they are bonded to hydrogen that is $\ce{HOCN}$ $\ce{HNCO}$. The two compounds will be different:

[image]

From [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyanate)

> Organic cyanates are called isocyanates when there is a $\ce{C−NCO}$ bond and cyanates when there is a $\ce{C−OCN}$ bond.

Due to resonance after deprotonation the two anions will be the same.

[image]