# How to write the formula of a mixed metal salt?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, nomenclature, salt

I suppose the formula of the *Sulphate salt of Sodium & Potassium* is $\ce{KNaSO4}$ as the [Pubchem site](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/Potassium-sodium-sulfate) says so.

So, is there any rule that in the formulae such mixed metal salts we need to write the metals in the order of electropositivity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"$\ce{KNaSO4}$" is correct, but not because of electronegativity order, but rather the alphabetical one.
From [IUPAC "Red Book"](https://iupac.org/what-we-do/books/redbook/), section IR-2.15 ORDERING PRINCIPLES [[1, p. 40](https://iupac.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/Red_Book_2005.pdf#page=52)]:

> IR-2.15.2 **Alphabetical order**
> Alphabetical order is used in *formulae* as follows.
>
> (a) Within the group of cations and within the group of anions, respectively, in formulae of salts and double salts.
> Deviations from this rule may be acceptable if it is desired to convey specific structural information, as in Example 5 below.
>
> Examples:
>
> 1. $\ce{BiClO}$ (anions $\ce{Cl-}$ and $\ce{O^2-})$
> 2. $\ce{NaOCl}$ (the anion is $\ce{OCl-},$ cf. Section IR-4.4.3.1)
> 3. $\ce{KNa4Cl(SO4)2}$
> 4. $\ce{CaTiO3}$ (perovskite type)
> 5. $\ce{SrFeO3}$ (perovskite type)

#### Reference

1. IUPAC “Red Book” *Nomenclature of Inorganic Chemistry*, 1st ed.; Connelly, N. G., Damhus, T., Hartshorn, R. M., Hutton, A. T., Eds.; IUPAC Recommendations; Royal Society of Chemistry: Cambridge, UK, **2005**. ([PDF](https://iupac.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/Red_Book_2005.pdf))

Comment: Related: [Is it NaOCl or NaClO?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/53568/what-is-the-structural-formula-of-alkali-hypohalite-mox-or-mxo/53577?r=SearchResults)