# Is there a difference between (HO)2 and H2O2?

Tags: nomenclature, stoichiometry

To me, it looks like the same thing. Is (HO)2 and H2O2 the same compound? When performing stoichiometric calculations, do they get treated the same?

Comment: There is no difference, except that nobody writes it as (HO)2. But that's just a matter of convenience.

Comment: [Relevant](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/33136)

Answer (score 0):

(HO)2 is identical to H2O2, except in the cases where ions are formed in water from this substance. For example, if you are using H2O2 as a proton donor, you may consider the following reaction :
$$\ce{H2O2->H+ + HO2-}$$
but this reaction could not be obtained and written from the formula (HO)2. So H2O2 is a better choice, and nobody used (HO)2.