Mixed chloride vs tetrachloroaluminate in nomenclature of alkali metal salts
I was reading an article and found AlCl4Cs named  aluminium caesium tetrachloride and AlCl4K was named  potassium tetrachloroaluminate .
Shouldnt be both named aluminium caesium tetrachloride and aluminium caesium tetrachloride, or potassium tetrachloroaluminate and caesium  tetrachloroaluminate?
What's the difference? Can I use both names?

The compound AlCl4Cs is technically $\ce{Cs^+[AlCl4]-}$ containing tetrachloroaluminate ($\ce{[AlCl4]^-}$) ions. So, the name should be caesium tetrachloroaluminate. This goes for other alkali salts.

Potassium/caesium tetrachloroaluminate ($\ce{M[AlCl4]}$) is the correct and preferred name.
Aluminium potassium/caesium tetrachloride invokes false impression that it is a binary chloride $\ce{MCl . AlCl3}$. In a way, it would be like saying $\ce{CaSO4}$ is calcium sulphur tetroxide.

$\ce{AlCl4M}$ is highly unusual format, formally following rules for empirical formulas with alphabetic element listing, but this approach is usually reserved for substances or mixtures with unknown structure . $\ce{ZnSO4}$ is not seen written as $\ce{O4SZn}$ either, or NaCl as ClNa.

"AlCl4M is weird and wrong." Not entirely. We sometimes see formulae written with all chemical symbols in alphabetical order; if that convention is used tge order AlCl4M is correct for all known alkali metals M.

Well, I am 59 and I have seen AlCl4K for the first time in my life. It may be formally correct for the summary formula, ignoring the structure and the presence of [AlCl4]-. But saying potassium tetrachloroaluminate has the formula AlCl4K is a kind of oxymoron. // More logically consistent would be aluminium potassium tetrachloride AlCl4K and potassium tetrachloroaluminate K[AlCl4], while both being the identical compounds.

See Beilstein type formula: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/33136/17368 (cc @OscarLanzi)

@NilayGhosh Yeah. but the organic chemistry is somewhat special. // We do not write ZnSO4 as O4SZn either.

In that case, you may find this answer also from Jan interesting ;)

@NilayGhosh Yeah, I know about these things. I do agree it is often matter of usual conventions and habits. Like circles where pouring milk to English tea is a mortal sin, versus circles where the opposite pouring is a mortal sin. What I just wanted to say, some obscure formulas do not bring any gain but raised eyebrows. So $\ce{H2O4S + N2O6Pb -> O4PbS + 2 HNO3}$  (that HNO3 looks weird, doesn't it?  :-) )

To the editor: 1)  \ce{} allows implicit subscripts without the explicit underscore, which is not wrong, but excessive. 2)  By IUPAC rules,  tetra- + oxide = tetroxide, mono- + oxide = monoxide, penta- + oxide = pentoxide.

Seems your post was edited by that vandal. Good thing, you rejected it.
